# drupal, OM Maximenu wraps all content divs with same css class

Tags: css, drupal

I'm working with OM Maximenu on a test site running drupal 7.
I have Maximenu running with several mini panels being displayed as dropdown menus in a main navigation menu.

The problem is that all the dropdown divs are being given the same class, and none have an ID. Each has the class: .om-maximenu-content. I can style one to be a fixed width and align to the page, but then the others will be offset by the same amount. I've looked through all the Maximenu settings again and again with no luck. Has anyone else faced this issue?

An additional question is this: Why does Maximenu generate so many empty divs around the content div? And why does it always always place the content in the om-maximenu-middle-right div?

I hope this is enough information. I imagine anyone who can answer this question will be familiar with Maximenu and won't need to look at my code. There is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Turns out the answer is deep selectors and .tpl file editing.**